# How can I show both data with two status using c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, windows, winforms

I have a form, in that I have user control(for displaying member name with datetime) and two comboboxes(one is cbstatus values like (refused , accepts , logout) and another combobox cbperiod and values like (today, 7 days, 30 days..) 
I am showing the member name along with visit datetime and logout datetime like this..)

by using the following query

```
  sql = @"SELECT member_Firstname, member_Lastname, member_Postcode,  
          visit_DateTime, visit_Status, visit_Logout_DateTime, visits.member_Id, visit_AlertMsg
          FROM members,visits
          WHERE members.member_Id = visits.member_Id
          AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'";
```

this is working fine .....

I am getting the values depends on the combobox values like this ..

```
 if (cbStatus.Text == "Accepts")
 {
    sql += " AND visits.visit_Status = 'accepted' ";
 }
```

i  have got the  two more conditions  like this...

```
  if (cbStatus.Text == "refusals")
 {
    sql += blahh blahh blahhhh
 }
```

i am getting values for selecting cbperiod combobox like this...

```
  if (cbPeriod.Text == "Today")
  {
    string dtStartString = DateTime.Today.ToString(DataHelper.dateFormat);

    sql += string.Format(" AND visits.visit_Date = '{0}'", dtStartString);
  }
//here i am comparing the cbstatus value logout and cbperiod text with today to get the member details whose logout datetime is today

  if (cbStatus.Text == "Logout" && cbPeriod.Text == "Today")
  {
    string dtStartString = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");            
    sql += string.Format(" AND DATE(visits.visit_Logout_DateTime) = '{0}'", dtStartString);

  }
```

and i have  got two more conditions like this.... for values in cbstatus and cbperiod

here i binding my  values with usercontrol....

```
 datatable dt1 =  Helper.GetData(sql);


  if (dt1 != null)
  {
    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {         
      foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
      {
        newItem = new EntryItem();// this is my usercontrol        
        if (cbStatus.Text != "Logout")
        {
          DateTime dtTemp = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_DateTime"].ToString()); // here I    am showing the data when user not selected the cbstatus text as logout I mean (refusal,..)
   but the below function overrides this data ....
          if (cbPeriod.Text == "Today") newItem.lblTime.Text = dtTemp.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss");
          else newItem.lblTime.Text = dtTemp.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");
        }

        if (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
          DateTime dtlogout = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"].ToString());
          if (dtlogout != null)
          {
            if (cbStatus.Text == "Logout" && cbPeriod.Text == "Today")
            {
              newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss");
              newItem.lblName.Text = row["member_Firstname"].ToString() + " " + row["member_Lastname"].ToString();
              newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text =  row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString();

            }
            else
              newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");
            newItem.lblName.Text = row["member_Firstname"].ToString() + " " + row["member_Lastname"].ToString();
            newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text = row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString();               
          }
        }

     newItem.lblName.Text = row["member_Firstname"].ToString() + " " + row["member_Lastname"].ToString();
        newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text =  row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString();
```

when i  select `cbstatus.text == logout` it will showing the correct data with members with logout datetime...

but when i select `cbstatus.text == refusals` .. it was showing logout data (members with logoutdaatetime) ..this is wrong actual it has to show the `refusal members` with `visit_Datetime`

how can i show both data with members has logoutdatetime and visit datetime

Note:one member have both logoutdatetime and visitdatetime....

and my data is like this...

```
  firstname     lastname   postcode   status        visit_Logout_DateTime        visit_datetime
-------------  --------   ---------   -------        ---------------------    ----------------
 rob           peter     hhd344h      refused          2011-05-06 12:09:07     2011-05-06 08:09:34                          
peter          chan      hy78kjk      refused          2011-09-08 12:09:08     2011-05-03 06:09:34
 rock         sam        yudufg3746h  refused          2011-08-08 09:08:45    
 rob           peter     hhd344h      refused          2011-05-10 12:09:07     2011-05-10 08:09:34
```

Comment: would any one pls help on this....and pls intimate me if the above question  is unclear...

Comment: I would simplify the code and make use of stored procedures, you have a lot of dynamic SQL.

Comment: but, I cannot use store procedures here .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem... like this....

```
        if (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value || row["visit_DateTime"] == DBNull.Value)
        {
          if (cbStatus.Text != "Refusals" && cbStatus.Text != "Accepts" && row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value)
          {
            DateTime dtlogout = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"].ToString());

            if (true)
            {
              if (cbPeriod.Text == "Today")
              {
                newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                newItem.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
              }
              else
                newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");               
              newItem.lblName.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_Firstname"].ToString(), row["member_Lastname"].ToString());
              newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_EntryMessage"].ToString(), row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString());

              newItem.lblName.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_Firstname"].ToString(), row["member_Lastname"].ToString());
              newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_EntryMessage"].ToString(), row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString());              
              newItem.tbHiddenId.Text = row["member_Id"].ToString();
              newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["member_Id"].ToString());
            }
          }

        }
        else if (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] == DBNull.Value || row["visit_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
          DateTime dtTemp = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_DateTime"].ToString());
          newItem.lblTime.Text = dtTemp.ToString(cbPeriod.Text == "Today" ? "HH':'mm':'ss" : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");

          newItem.lblName.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_Firstname"].ToString(), row["member_Lastname"].ToString());
          newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", row["member_EntryMessage"].ToString(), row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString());

          newItem.tbHiddenId.Text = row["member_Id"].ToString();
          newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["member_Id"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the case statement in sql. See the following example

```
sql = @"SELECT member_Firstname, member_Lastname, member_Postcode,             visit_DateTime, visit_Status, visit_Logout_DateTime, visits.member_Id, visit_AlertMsg , CustomDateColumn = CASE  visit_Status
WHEN 'refused' THEN   visit_Datetime
WHEN 'Logout' THEN  visit_Logout_DateTime
WHEN ....
End
FROM members,visits           WHERE members.member_Id = visits.member_Id           AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing some brackets around the else statement that looks like this:

```
else
    newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");
newItem.lblName.Text = row["member_Firstname"].ToString() + " " + row["member_Lastname"].ToString();
newItem.lblAlertMessage.Text = row["visit_AlertMsg"].ToString();
```

Also, it appears that the first line of this block might be the answer to your problem. You are changing the label to the "logout" time. Perhaps you want to actually use the "visit" time?